# How to ensure same thread no re enter in code block

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, console

I'm making something like a web crawler in java console app, I got a class that implements runnable interface, and in method run, I got the operation I want to do (e.x. a for loop that iterate every url is given as input and do inside all the computations).

I want each iterate to be done by different thread. So I created a threadpool using executorsservice (num of threads same as num of urls) and I used synchronized keyword to allow only one thread at a time inside to execute the block of computation.

But how I can ensure that the same thread will not reenter first inside code block again? if it is needed I will post code snippet later.

Thanks.

The output i get is the following:

I'm searching with 2 keywords each url. this example is 1 url and 2 keywords.

Current Thread: pool-1-thread-2 -----------------
Current Thread: pool-1-thread-1 -----------------

Title: Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
URL:  https://en.wikipedia.org
Times keyword  Free Found:  41

Title: Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
URL:  https://en.wikipedia.org
Times keyword  Free Found:  41

Title: Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
URL:  https://en.wikipedia.org
Times keyword  Wikibooks Found:  82

Title: Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
URL:  https://en.wikipedia.org
Times keyword  Wikibooks Found:  82

I think i made it in some way, but i'm facing new problems now for e.g. see comments inside run method.

```
        public class KeywordCounter {

        private List keylist;
        private List weblist;

        public KeywordCounter(List keywordlist, List listWebsites) {
            this.keylist = new ArrayList(keywordlist);
            this.weblist = new ArrayList(listWebsites);

        }

        public void threadCreate(List klist, List listWebsites) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);


            for (int w = 0; w < this.weblist.size(); w++) {

                executor.execute(new Runnable() {

                    private List keylist = new ArrayList(klist);
                    private List weblist = new ArrayList(listWebsites);

                    @Override
                    public synchronized void run() {
System.out.println("Current Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName().toString() + " ")

// Computations i want one thread inside here each time but i think both threads are entering same time cause i saw 4 results instaid of 2.
//Also i want inside here to pass the w variable of the for loop, cause i need it for further computations how i can achieve this?.

                });

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not describe you code. Instead, create a [mcve] and include it in your question (use the [edit] link). Making the code synchronized doesn't sound right, and it's not clear where your problem really lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The "Critical Section"

If you have two URLs then you will have two Threads. One thread for one URL and the other Thread for the other URL. Both are started at the same time.

Now we have a piece of code that must not be executed in paralell but all the other code must be executed in parallel. The piece of code must be executed sequientiel! We call this piece of code the "Critical Section".

### The "Synchronized" keyword

To mark a section as critical in java you may use the synchronized statement:

```
01 mulithread-code
02 mulithread-code
03 mulithread-code
04 synchronized {
05   critical code
06   critical code
07 }
08 mulithread-code
09 mulithread-code
10 mulithread-code
```

Having two threads, the first thread who joins line `04` will be started without any delay. The second thread will wait. The first thread will do all the work from line `05` to line `06`.

Then the magic happens: As soon as the first thread leaves line `07`, the second thread stops his wait and continue his work: Thread two will start to execute line `05` and then `06`.

Comment: yes, i wasn't synchronizing the Runnable.class. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Before some code, it's hard to say, but you're on the correct way. Try to use BlockingQueue also. If you have more than 1 thread, with the queue and if every thread does work with the same time, you can sure it wouldn`t be a loop.
Of course, if your thread1 do work in 1ms and your thread2 do work in 1 min, so... without any blocking.

Try to use [wait/notify also](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify)

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Client2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ExecutorService pool= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        ExecutorCompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(pool);

        List<String> url=Arrays.asList("www.goole.in","www.abc.com");
        for(int i=0;i<url.size();i++) {
        completionService.submit(new MyCallable(url.get(i)));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<url.size();i++) {
        try {
            Future<String> s=completionService.take();
            System.out.println(s.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }
    }

}

 class MyCallable implements Callable<String>{

    String Url;
    public MyCallable(String url) {
        this.Url=url;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
    //process the URL
        return Url+" Processed.";
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to write callable task in which you describe your activity. and these task submitted to ExecutorCompletionService .